# Écriture épicène

Tags: genre-biologique

Quel est aujourd'hui le statut du langage épicène dans l'Hexagone et dans les autres pays de la francophonie ? On lit par exemple quelques règles ici :

https://www.unige.ch/rectorat/egalite/ancrage/epicene/

https://www.hepl.ch/files/live/sites/systemsite/files/instance-egalite/petit_guide_epicene_ipe.pdf

Sont-elles respectées ? Doit-on les respecter du moins lorsqu'on prépare un document administratif ou donne un discours ?

Dans une écriture épicène, des phrases comme ci-dessous sont-elles acceptables ?

> Le chef ou la cheffe seront satisfaits.
>
> Les chef(fe)s seront satisfait(e)s.
>
> Les chefs ou les cheffes seront satisfait(e)s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En France, une controverse existe entre les partisans de l'écriture inclusive, qui revendiquent l'égalité hommes/femmes jusque dans la langue parce que la façon dont on dit les choses influence la façon dont on les pense, et ceux de l'Académie française qui arguent que les règles grammaticales sont désormais établies et ne concernent que la grammaire et pas la société. Les premiers reprochent aux seconds de n'être que des phallocrates vieillissants et les seconds reprochent aux premiers de vouloir détruire un héritage multi-centenaire.

En attendant, l'administration reste proche de l'Académie française, et l'écriture inclusive est encore un marqueur socio-politique.

Personnellement, ces deux approches me choquent beaucoup moins que les fautes d'orthographe et de grammaire que je vois de plus en plus dans les journaux, les magazines et jusque dans les sous-titres des films et séries.

Comment: Serait-ce à dire qu'opter pour le falbala de l'écriture inclusive n'équivaudrait pour l'instant qu' à témoigner en actes pour le moins illégitimes d'un certain parti pris pour un mouvement contestataire ?

Comment: Je vois plutôt que mouviciel affirme que les deux côtés ont leurs arguments, valides tous deux dans une certaine mesure, et que l'administration a une tendance à se ranger du côté de l'Académie, ce qui mène à son affirmation que l'écriture inclusive est un marqueur socio-politique. Je n'en conclus rien quant à son opinion personnelle, qui semble de toute manière plus sensible aux fautes d'orthographe et de grammaire qu'au style inclusif ou exclusif choisi par la personne ou l'organisme s'exprimant.

Comment: Si l'administration se rangeait du côté de ceux qui revendiquent l'inclusion plutôt que du côté de l'Académie, les irréductibles de la grammaire classique pourraient à leur tour être assimilés à une certaine vision socio-politique. Mouviciel exprime la situation d'une façon qui laisse le lecteur libre de choisir son interprétation personnelle, ce qui me semble louable (et lui vaut de surcroît un vote de ma part).

Comment: On peut aussi noter que le propos de l'Ac. est beaucoup plus nuancé que ce qu'on dit souvent et qu'il [évolue](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/actualites/la-feminisation-des-noms-de-metiers-et-de-fonctions).

Answer (score 4):

Dans l'Hexagone depuis une circulaire de 1986 il est conseillé dès que possible d'utiliser la double flexion (`le chef ou la cheffe`) dans un cadre administratif. Ainsi la [circulaire d'Edouard Philippe de 2017](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000036068906), même si elle marque un rapprochement vers la position de l'académie française, précise:

> Suivant la même logique, je vous demande de systématiquement recourir, dans les actes de recrutement et les avis de vacances publiés au Journal officiel, à des formules telles que « le candidat ou la candidate » afin de ne pas marquer de préférence de genre.

Concernant la formulation épicène on remarquera que plutôt que les parenthèses il est recommandé (par exemple par le [HCE](http://www.haut-conseil-egalite.gouv.fr/) qui a publié un [guide](http://www.haut-conseil-egalite.gouv.fr/IMG/pdf/guide_pour_une_communication_publique_sans_stereotype_de_sexe_vf_2016_11_02.compressed.pdf) détaillé) d'utiliser des points (`.`) ou des points médians (`·`).

---

Personnellement si c'est un document ou discours officiel je conseillerais la première formulation proposée:

> Le chef ou la cheffe seront satisfaits.

Car comme l'a très bien dit mouviciel certaines personnes risquent de voir dans l'usage des points ou points médians un acte politique qu'elles désapprouvent.